# Windows context menu for multiple files [C++]

Tags: c++, windows, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu that support multiple files.

I read through SO and understand that either you must use DDE or shell extension (something to do with creating and registering COM object). However all the sourcecodes I found are in C#.

I then decided to go with COM object. I found 1 in C++ that uses COM but it's dated 2006, so I just don't know if it's outdated. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx

Can anyone shed me some light on this? And is there any good and new article out there covering this issue?

Or if anyone has some something similar before using DDE and IPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine, the underlying mechanic hasn't changed in the last 4 years.

Take a look at the comments at the bottom of the article, people are using it without problems. (There is also a link to a VS 2008 template for multiple-files)

Comment: great thanks for the note. Will try it out later :-) Any advice on the DDE/IPC part?

Comment: I just tried out the template. Doesn't seem to work. I'm running Windows 7. Any clue at all?